# PHP: Parsing a Post Response containing Multipart Form Data

Tags: php, arrays, curl, multipartform-data

I have been working with an API and I used to run a cron job and make an API call every 5 minutes. Recently they introduced an feature similar to PayPal IPN which posts variables once the order gets response.

I did print the post variables and mailed it to have a look at what the response would be. This is the code I used.

```
$post_var = "Results: " . print_r($_POST, true);
mail('email@mail.com', "Post Variables", $post_var);
```

and I got this in the mail.

```
Results: Array
(
    [--------------------------918fc8da7040954f
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "ID"

1
--------------------------918fc8da7040954f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="TXN"

1234567890
--------------------------918fc8da7040954f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Comment"

This is a test comment
--------------------------918fc8da7040954f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ConnectID"

1
--------------------------918fc8da7040954f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ConnectName"

Test Connect (nonexisting)
--------------------------918fc8da7040954f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Status"

Unavailable
--------------------------918fc8da7040954f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CallbackURL"

http://www.example.com/ipn
--------------------------918fc8da7040954f--

)
```

Now I need the values of ID i.e. 1, TXN i.e. 1234567890 etc., I never worked with these kind of array. How do I proceed and what is the response I have actually got. Is this a cUrl response or multipart form data response?

Please explain it to me if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$response` contains your multi-part content:

```
// Match the boundary name by taking the first line with content
preg_match('/^(?<boundary>.+)$/m', $response, $matches);

// Explode the response using the previously match boundary
$parts = explode($matches['boundary'], $response);

// Create empty array to store our parsed values
$form_data = array();

foreach ($parts as $part)
{
    // Now we need to parse the multi-part content. First match the 'name=' parameter,
    // then skip the double new-lines, match the body and ignore the terminating new-line.
    // Using 's' flag enables .'s to match new lines.
    $matched = preg_match('/name="?(?<key>\w+).*?\n\n(?<value>.*?)\n$/s', $part, $matches);

    // Did we get a match? Place it in our form values array
    if ($matched)
    {
        $form_data[$matches['key']] = $matches['value'];
    }
}

// Check the response...
print_r($form_data);
```

I'm sure there's a lot of caveats to this approach so your mileage may vary, but it satisfied my need (parsing a BitBucket snippet API response).